# ANOVA or regression: One categorical independent variable, one continuous independent variable and one dependent variable

Tags: multiple-regression, anova

I am conducting a study with the following design:

- Independent variable 1 (IV1): categorical variable with four levels
- Independent variable 2 (IV2): continuous variable - mean scores on 9 questions, each of which is measured on a range from 1 to 5
- Dependent variable (DV): variable range 1 to 7

Firstly, my DV seems to be categorical variable with 7 levels but I would prefer to treat it as a bounded continuous variable. Can I do that and how?

How do I test the relation between these variables? I am interested in both main and interaction effects.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Does your dependent variable have an order to it, such as terrible/bad/neutral/good/excellent?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, indeed. DV is a rated variable: low to high. IV2 is a mean of such ratings for multiple questions